# When installing ESXi 7.0 on a VM hosted by ESXi 5.5, installer does not detect any disks?

Tags: vmware

This is a old lab environment with a ESXi5.5 server which I cannot upgrade since it is not owned by me. I need to setup a ESXi 7.0 for educational reasons.

As stated in the subject, I need to install ESXi 7.0 in a VM that is hosted on a ESXi 5.5 host, when booting the ESXi 7.0 installer, all is fine, I get prompted with the EULA but when I am prompted to select which disk to install on, no disks appear.

I was able to install ESXi 6.7 on this VM, so there is no issue with the VM itself.

I have attempted:

- Install using a HPE custom ESXi image.
- with ESXi image builder, add pretty much all available extra drivers from VMware.
- All form of different settings on the 5.5 host in regards to how the VM boots, how and where the datastore for the virtual disks would be stored etc.

The ESXi 5.5 hypervisor is hosted on a a HPE BL460 g9 server.

It seems it simply is not possible and the only reason I haven't given  up is that this is my only way to setup a lab environment, there simply are no alternatives available to me.

The reason why it must be ESXi 7.0 is both related to its features but also for license availability.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is the VM configured as UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: @Ramhound It is configured as UEFI but i have also tried to set it as BIOS but it had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

I finally solved this by switching the SCSi controller to paravirtual on the VM.